# Can someone explain this paragraph to me from the Rails Security Guide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, ember.js, csrf

See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

---

[Rails CSRF protection] will automatically include a security token, calculated from the current session and the server-side secret, in all forms and Ajax requests generated by Rails. **You won’t need the secret, if you use CookieStorage as session storage.** If the security token doesn’t match what was expected, the session will be reset.

---

I'm really hoping that someone could explain to my why the server side secret is not needed if I store the entire session in a cookie.

The reason I ask is because I am trying to figure out if there is a way to generate CSRF tokens in a 100% client-side application *(ember.js)* where I won't have Rails inserting a CSRF token on all forms.  I can certainly write to cookies using JavaScript, and I can certainly hash various values.

If there is some way to generate a cookie client-side using JavaScript, without a server-side secret, and being able to verify on the server please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try googling this?

There is plenty of information on jQuery/ember.js/Rails CSRF out there. jQuery has an [`$.ajaxPrefilter`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) which you can use to append the CSRF token from your META tags to the request headers *(and having said META tags existing on page for a single page app shouldn't be a problem)*.

[This article](http://blog.waymondo.com/2012-12-18-ember-dot-js-and-rails-authentication-gotchas/) provides one implemenation that uses this method (the example is in Coffeescript).

```
$ ->
  token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  $.ajaxPrefilter (options, originalOptions, xhr) ->
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
```

[Here is another implemenation](https://gist.github.com/leepfrog/4284160) extending the `DS.RESTAdapter`.

All Rails is doing in a 'normal' application is adding the CSRF token as a hidden input field to your forms. Whether coming this way or as an HTTP request header, it's picked up on by rails just the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have googled around - there is a pile of information out there and I don't have the background to fully understand what I am getting myself into.  The heart of my question was more if there is a way to prevent CSRF from an Ember app that is distributed **not** using Rails.  Is there a way to generate a CSRF token simply client-side?  Or is using an `auth_token` on every request (via `ember-auth`) enough to prevent CSRF?

Comment: @Deefour: Your explanation of how the CSRF token gets added to headers for an AJAX request is good, but I don't see how it addresses the question -- why is the secret needed for some session stores and not for others?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be if using CookieSessionStore in Rails, there will be a secret token used to sign cookie. Rails may use that secret token instead to verify